# Search and replace in Apache Spark

Tags: join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

We have created two dataset sentenceDataFrame, sentenceDataFrame2 where search replace should happen.

sentenceDataFrame2 stores the search and replace terms.

We also performed all 11 types of join 'inner', 'outer', 'full', 'fullouter', 'leftouter', 'left', 'rightouter', 'right', 'leftsemi', 'leftanti', 'cross' none of them gave us the result.

Can you please let us know Where we are going Wrong and Kindly point us in the right direction.

```
        List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create(0, "Allen jeevi pramod Allen"),
            RowFactory.create(1,"sandesh Armstrong jeevi"),
            RowFactory.create(2,"harsha Nischay DeWALT"));

        StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
        new StructField("label", DataTypes.IntegerType, false,
          Metadata.empty()),
        new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false,
          Metadata.empty()) });
        Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);


        List<Row> data2 = Arrays.asList(
          RowFactory.create("Allen", "Apex Tool Group"),
          RowFactory.create("Armstrong","Apex Tool Group"),
          RowFactory.create("DeWALT","StanleyBlack"));

        StructType schema2 = new StructType(new StructField[] {
        new StructField("label2", DataTypes.StringType, false,
          Metadata.empty()),
        new StructField("sentence2", DataTypes.StringType, false,
          Metadata.empty()) });
        Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema2);

        Dataset<Row> remainingElements=sentenceDataFrame.join(sentenceDataFrame2,sentenceDataFrame.col("label").equalTo(sentenceDataFrame2.col("label2")),"cross");
        System.out.println("Left anti join count :"+remainingElements.count());
```

**Input**

Allen jeevi pramod Allen
sandesh Armstrong jeevi
harsha Nischay DeWALT

**Expected Output**

Apex Tool Group jeevi pramod Apex Tool Group
sandesh Apex Tool Group jeevi
harsha Nischay StanleyBlack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For join conditions that don't involve simple equalities like this, you're going to need to use Spark User-Defined Functions (UDFs).

Here's a JUnit code snippet that won't compile directly, but shows the relevant imports and logic. The Java API is quite verbose, though. I'll leave the problem of doing this in Scala as an exercise for the reader. It will be much more concise.

The static import is required for the `callUDF()` and `col()` methods.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF2;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF3;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

@Test
public void testSomething() {
    List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
        RowFactory.create(0, "Allen jeevi pramod Allen"),
        RowFactory.create(1, "sandesh Armstrong jeevi"),
        RowFactory.create(2, "harsha Nischay DeWALT")
    );

    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
        new StructField("label", DataTypes.IntegerType, false, Metadata.empty()),
        new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()) 
    });
    Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

    List<Row> data2 = Arrays.asList(
        RowFactory.create("Allen", "Apex Tool Group"),
        RowFactory.create("Armstrong","Apex Tool Group"),
        RowFactory.create("DeWALT","StanleyBlack")
    );

    StructType schema2 = new StructType(new StructField[] {
        new StructField("label2", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
        new StructField("sentence2", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()) 
    });
    Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema2);

    UDF2<String, String, Boolean> contains = new UDF2<String, String, Boolean>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5239951370238629896L;

        @Override
        public Boolean call(String t1, String t2) throws Exception {
            return t1.contains(t2);
        }
    };
    spark.udf().register("contains", contains, DataTypes.BooleanType);

    UDF3<String, String, String, String> replaceWithTerm = new UDF3<String, String, String, String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2882956931420910207L;

        @Override
        public String call(String t1, String t2, String t3) throws Exception {
            return t1.replaceAll(t2, t3);
        }
    };
    spark.udf().register("replaceWithTerm", replaceWithTerm, DataTypes.StringType);

    Dataset<Row> joined = sentenceDataFrame.join(sentenceDataFrame2, callUDF("contains", sentenceDataFrame.col("sentence"), sentenceDataFrame2.col("label2")))
                                           .withColumn("sentence_replaced", callUDF("replaceWithTerm", sentenceDataFrame.col("sentence"), sentenceDataFrame2.col("label2"), sentenceDataFrame2.col("sentence2")))
                                           .select(col("sentence_replaced"));

    joined.show(false);
}
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|sentence_replaced                           |
+--------------------------------------------+
|Apex Tool Group jeevi pramod Apex Tool Group|
|sandesh Apex Tool Group jeevi               |
|harsha Nischay StanleyBlack                 |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use replaceAll and UDF fuctions to achieve the expected output.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]"));
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JavaTokenizerExample").getOrCreate();

        List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
        RowFactory.create(0, "Allen jeevi pramod Allen"),
        RowFactory.create(1, "sandesh Armstrong jeevi"),
        RowFactory.create(2, "harsha Nischay DeWALT")
    );

        StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
        new StructField("label", DataTypes.IntegerType, false,
                Metadata.empty()),
        new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false,
                Metadata.empty()) });
        Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);
        UDF1 mode = new UDF1<String, String>() {
            public String call(final String types) throws Exception {
                return types.replaceAll("Allen", "Apex Tool Group")
                .replaceAll("Armstrong","Apex Tool Group")
                .replaceAll(""DeWALT","StanleyBlack"")
            }
        };

        sqlContext.udf().register("mode", mode, DataTypes.StringType);

        sentenceDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("people");
        Dataset<Row> newDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT mode(sentence), label FROM people").withColumnRenamed("UDF(sentence)", "sentence");
        newDF.show(false);
}
}
```

output

```
  +--------------------------------------------+------+
  |sentence                                    |label |
  +--------------------------------------------+------+
  |Apex Tool Group jeevi pramod Apex Tool Group|  0   |
  |sandesh Apex Tool Group jeevi               |  1   |
  |harsha Nischay StanleyBlack                 |  2   |
  +--------------------------------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Still facing with a similar problem

**Input**

Allen Armstrong jeevi pramod Allen
sandesh Armstrong jeevi
harsha nischay DeWALT

**Output**

Apex Tool Group Armstrong jeevi pramod Apex Tool Group
Allen Apex Tool Group jeevi pramod Allen
sandesh Apex Tool Group jeevi
harsha nischay StanleyBlack

**Expected Output**

Apex Tool Group Apex Tool Group jeevi pramod Apex Tool Group
sandesh Apex Tool Group jeevi
harsha nischay StanleyBlack

Got this output when there are multiple replacements do in a row.

Are there any other method which must be followed to get the proper output.? Or is this is limitation of UDF ?